# If $S \subset M$ is an immersed submanifold then the inclusion map $i: S \to M$ is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $S \subset M$ be an immersed submanifold and $i:S \to M$ the inclusion map. In this case, why is the differential $i_*: T_p S \to T_p M$ injective, i.e. $i$ is an immersion?

The definition of an immersed submanifold means that $S$ is an image of some $f:N \to M$ that is a one-to-one immersion. How does this imply that the inclusion map from $S$ to $M$ is an immersion?

Comment: The question is ill-posed, since the tangent space $T_pS$ is undefined.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What do you mean the space is undefined?

Comment: I mean that $S$ is just a subset, so it does not have a tangent space at all its points. Just think about figure 8 curve in the plane. What is its tangent space at the self-intersection point? It is undefined.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $S$ is a manifold, not just a subset. We can view the figure 8 curve as an immersed submanifold. For example, in my text, they give it as the image of a one-to-one immersion $(\cos t,\sin(2t)), -\pi/2<t<3\pi/2$ or as the image of a one-ton-one immersion $(\cos t,-\sin (2t)), -\pi/2<t<3\pi/2$.

Comment: The issue is that $S$ is just a subset, all you know is that it is the image of an injective immersion. But this injective immersion is not unique. Thus, for different injective immersions $f, g$ with image $S$, for the same point $x\in S$ you get different images $df_y(T_yN)$ and $dg_z(T_zN)$, $f(y)=g(z)=x\in S$. This is exactly what happens with the figure 8.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It is defined to be a manifold in my text. It is given the topology and differentiable structure inherited from the one-to-one immersion $f$. So for that example, the two maps induce distinct immersed submanifold structures on the figure-eight. I do not see why $S$ would not be a manifold under this definition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Immersed_submanifolds It is also stated in the Properties of this wiki link that the inclusion map of any immersed submanifold is an immersion. I cannot come up with a proof of this fact, however.

Comment: May I know which texts are you using?

Comment: @ArcticChar Lowing Tu's An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tilde{f}:N\to S$ be the bijection obtained by restricting the codomain of $f$. As the topology and the differentiable structure is induced by $\tilde{f}$, $\tilde f$ is a diffeomorphism. Then $i=f\circ\tilde f ^{-1}$ is differentiable. By the chain rule

$$D_pf=D_p(i\circ\tilde f)=D_{\tilde f(p)}i\circ D_p\tilde f.
$$

As $f$ is an immersion $D_pf$ is injective. Also $D_p\tilde f$ is invertible so $D_{\tilde f(p)}i$ must be injective for all $p$ and hence $i$ is an immersion.

Comment: Why is the topology of $S$ induced by $\tilde f$?

Comment: If i understood OP‘s comments correctly the immersion $f$ is part of the data of $S$. So $S$ is not just a subset which is the image of *some* injective immersion, it comes with a distinguished injective immersion $f$ from which it gets it‘s topology and differentiable structure.